# How to use React NumberFormat package in conjunction with Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, number-formatting, formik

I have a Formik Field that I want to use alongside the React [NumberFormat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) npm package. This is my FormGroup within Formik:

```js
//...Other code
                <Formik
                    initialValues={this.state.diamondPurchaseGstDetails}
                    enableReinitialize={true}
                    onSubmit={this.formSubmit}
                >
                    {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
                        <Form>
                                    <FormGroup>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="CreditDays"
                                            type="text"
                                            component={ParseNumber}
                                        ></Field>
                                        <Label>Credit Days</Label>
                                    </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
//...Other code
```

The component I am passing is my custom component `ParseNumber` which uses the NumberFormat package. Here's the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

function ParseNumber() {
    return (
        <NumberFormat decimalScale={0} allowNegative={false}/>
    )
}

export default ParseNumber;
```

Now, my question is how do I bind the input Field value to the `values` prop? I tried something like `value={values.CreditDays}` but it didn't seem to work.

Edit: Here's the working codesandbox link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-leftpad-x6klg?file=/src/Form.js)

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: @NishargShah I have added the snippet as suggested.

Comment: @Darner already added the answer, if you not satisfied with that answer, tag me I will lookout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Field` component, and the `useField` hook both supply useful props and values respectively. Namely an object called `field`, which holds `name` ,`value`, `onChange`, and `onBlur`. These can just be spread over whichever component you're trying to bind to formik

Using hooks (`useField`) is my prefered method

```
import { useField } from 'formik'

function NumberFieldHooks(props) {
  const { name } = props
  const [field] = useField(name)
  
  return <NumberFormat {...field} decimalScale={0} allowNegative={false}/>
}

function NumberField({ field }) {
  return <NumberFormat {...field} decimalScale={0} allowNegative={false} />;
}

// later in the formik component
return (
  <Formik {...props}>
    <Form>
      {/* using the hooks form */}
      <NumberFieldHooks name="CreditDaysHooks" />

      {/* using the component prop */}
      <Field name="CreditDays" component={NumberField} />
    </Form>
  </Formik>
)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Using the component prop method, can I pass custom attributes like styling classes from the Field component to the NumberField component?

Comment: of course, just don't forget to reference them in the component itself. As the docs, say, *All additional props will be passed through.*

Comment: @Datner can you have a look at my question regarding formik and number format? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888296/how-to-use-react-number-format-with-formik